# Google OAuth exception

Tags: google-oauth

We encountered OAuth exception when opening authorization page from our website. It lasted for a few mins and impacted different customers. I am wondering if there is any known issue during that time (19:45- 19:59 PST time).

Error:

```
"Ajax error [411], error, <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\"\http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\>\r\n<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Length Required</TITLE>\r\n<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Content-Type\" Content=\"text/html; charset=us-ascii\"></HEAD>\r\n<BODY><h2>Length Required</h2>\r\n<hr><p>HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.</p>\r\n</BODY></HTML>\r\n"
```

Comment: Are you asking on stack overflow if google had an outage?

Comment: Hi @Evert, it looks like this is the only place where we can post Google oauth related questions. If you are aware of any official google forum, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Also Google Ads API forum won't be able to solve OAuth related question. I am looking for a more official channel to talk with Google support team, thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is certainly not the place either. Google shouldn't offload their support to the community.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about historical outages on a google service.